# Q: How to dynamically expand records

Tags: excel, transformation, powerquery

I have a use-case where I have multiple columns containing records that I want to expand dynamically. Meaning that the name of the columns to expand is not hardcoded.

```
Expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "HardcodedColumnName", {"fieldname"}, {"fieldname"}),
```

My M code snipped below can expand records dynamically based on a transformation table. But I cannot get my head around how to expand the column name dynamically as well. For context, my real data set has a lot of columns to expand, and the amount of columns change over time. I am looking for a scalable method of expanding all these columns.

```
let
   //Use-case: dynamically expand 'name for 'user' and 'timezone' for 'city',
   //          i e expand records w/o hardcoded column- or field names

   Source = Table.FromRecords(
            {
               [key = 1, user = [id = 10, name = "Wayne Carter"], city = [id = 2, name = "Wuhan", timezone = "China Standard Time"]],
               [key = 2, user = [id = 20, name = "Hugh Jass"], city = [id = 1, name = "Milan", timezone = "Central European Time"]],
               [key = 3, user = [id = 30, name = "Ben Dover"], city = [id = 2, name = "Wuhan", timezone = "China Standard Time"]]
            }),

   //Table controls which attribute to expand
   TransformationTable = Table.FromRecords(
            {
               [field = "user", attribute = "name"],
               [field = "city", attribute = "timezone"]
            }),

   //Transformation table lookup
   AttributeLookup = (parameter as text) =>
   let 
      value = Table.SelectRows(TransformationTable, each ([field] = parameter))[attribute]{0}
   in
      value,

   //These rows are hardcoded for columns 'user' and 'city' - how to make this dynamic?
   ExpandedTable1 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "user", {AttributeLookup("user")}, {AttributeLookup("user")}),
   ExpandedTable2 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ExpandedTable1, "city", {AttributeLookup("city")}, {AttributeLookup("city")}),

in
   ExpandedTable2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use something like the code below to achieve this:

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromRecords({
        [key = 1, user = [id = 10, name = "Wayne Carter"], city = [id = 2, name = "Wuhan", timezone = "China Standard Time"]],
        [key = 2, user = [id = 20, name = "Hugh Jass"], city = [id = 1, name = "Milan", timezone = "Central European Time"]],
        [key = 3, user = [id = 30, name = "Ben Dover"], city = [id = 2, name = "Wuhan", timezone = "China Standard Time"]]
    }),
    expansionMap = [
        user = {"name"},
        city = {"timezone"}
    ],
    dynamicallyExpanded = List.Accumulate(Record.FieldNames(expansionMap), someTable, (tableState as table, recordColumnName as text) as table =>
        let
            fieldNamesToExpand = Record.Field(expansionMap, recordColumnName),
            fieldNamesAfterExpansion = fieldNamesToExpand,
            expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tableState, recordColumnName, fieldNamesToExpand, fieldNamesAfterExpansion)
        in expanded
    )
in
    dynamicallyExpanded
```

- `expansionMap` is a `record` in which:

  - the field names (i.e. `user`, `city`) map to the names of columns containing records (which need expanding)
  - the field values (i.e. `{"name"}` and `{"timezone"}`) map to the nested fields (and which will eventually be columns in the expanded table).
- All the code above does is loop over the field names in `expansionMap` whilst iteratively expanding each specified record column.
- Column names in a table must be unique so if you, for example, specified that you wanted to expand `id` in the `user` record column and `id` in the `city` record column, I think you'd eventually get an error (saying there is already a column named `id`). To pre-empt this, you could implement some logic to rename the expanded columns in a way that they should not match any existing column name. For example, you could change the relevant line in the code to: `fieldNamesAfterExpansion = List.Transform(fieldNamesToExpand, each Text.Combine({recordColumnName, _}, ".")),`.

---

This isn't truly dynamic. That is, you know the names of the record columns (which you want to expand) in advance and at the time of writing the code. But if I've understood your question correctly, you just want to represent your record columns via some abstract structure -- and write some code that can then consume/process that structure.

Comment: Thx, Chillin, for a truly elegant solution! I tested out you code and this is the first time I have come across 'List.Accumulate' and it is the bees knees. This use-case will obviously always require a mapping table between column name and the field within the record to expand, so in that sense it will not be fully dynamic. But with a few lines of code to detect source columns of data type 'records', and a lookup to ensure there is a mapping defined in 'extensionMap', this would scale nicely. A big THANK YOU for taking your time to educate a PQ beginner.